# Resolve a conditional expression including Exists and ForAll

Tags: simplifying-expressions, conditional

I don't know the `Resolve` function exactly, especially when involved with `Exists`  and `ForAll`, could you please help me in the following example?

> $\forall C$, can we find some $x>0$, such that
>   $$
> c(x)=(C+2x)x^2+C^2x+2Cx^2+C\geq0,
> $$
>   and 
>   $$
> C<-2x
> $$
>   holds at the sametime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Exists[x,  x > 0 && ForAll[c, c < -2 x && (c + 2 x) x^2 + c^2 x + 2 c x^2 >= 0]]
Resolve[%]

(* False *)
```

Edit: In thinking about this, I perhaps took the question as stated too literally and that's not what you meant, i.e., it is obvious that it is not true that for all C, `C <-2 X`, which the above shows. However, if you meant (and I *think* this true) *for all C with the condition `C < -2 X`*, that's done this way:

```
Exists[x, x > 0, ForAll[c, c < -2 x, (c + 2 x) x^2 + c^2 x + 2 c x^2 >= 0]]
Reduce[%]

(* True *)
```

You can use `FindInstance` to get instance(s), like:

```
FindInstance[x > 0 && c < -2 x && (c + 2 x) x^2 + c^2 x + 2 c x^2 >= 0, {x, c}, Reals]

(*  {{x -> 1, c -> -4}}  *)
```

Comment: @van abel: thanks for accept, please check update, I might have taken your question too literally... and there was a typo (`cx` instead of multiplication `c x`)